# Bootstrap 5 currentColor issue with vertical ruler (vr)

Tags: jquery, css, angular, bootstrap-5

I am using `vr` from Bootstrap 5 to create a vertical ruler divisions in `col-sm-1` between three chartjs graphs in `col-sm-3`, my issue is that one `vr` is a bit darker than the other, I haven't been able to figure out the same, also if I add `style="justify-content: center;"` to the row the rulers switch colors, the one darker becomes lighter and vice versa.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card border-0">
        <div class="card-body bg-body rounded">
            
            <div class="row" style="justify-content: center;">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="container">
                        foobar1
                        <canvas id="one"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1 align-self-center">
                    <div class="d-flex" style="justify-content: center;">
                        <div class="vr" style="height: 120px;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="container">
                        foobar2
                        <canvas id="two"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1 align-self-center">
                    <div class="d-flex" style="justify-content: center;">
                        <div class="vr" style="height: 120px;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="container">
                        foobar3
                        <canvas id="three"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Corresponding js code

```
 const anyctx = document.getElementById('one') as any;
 const foobar1 = new Chart(anyctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'foobar',
        data: data,
        backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'],
        borderColor: ['rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'],
        borderWidth: 1,
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

If row is not center justified the second ruler is a bit darker.

[image: one without row justification centerd]

If row is center justified the first ruler is a bit darker.

[image: one with row justification centered]

Upon inspecting the element, the background color property is set to `currentColor` in both situations for both rulers, so, what is going on here?

P.S. using Angular if it makes any difference but I guess it doesn't at all.

Answer (score 0):

according to Bootstrap, if it's using currentColor, you should be able to change the colour by adding a text-{color} class. It's the only way I could think of to change the colors. You can check the doc [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/spinners/#colors). For instance you could add `<div class="vr text-dark"></div>` to all of your vertical lines. I know I answered late but I hope this can mitigate your problem at least a little.